# Best way to replicate the 8 little square of Photoshop transform tool with CSS

Tags: css

I'd like some containers on my page to have a 1px stroke with eight little squares just like the Photoshop selection tool below (but without the cross at the center). I want to replicate this border adorned with squares, not the empty, blue space in between as my container can contain any type of content and be of any size.

[image]

One solution is to create eight absolutely positioned elements inside my containers then position each one separately. Another solution is to use multiple backgrounds, but because my container occupy the full width of my page that would entail to create a slightly wider wrapper carrying the multiple backgrounds. Not great because not simple.

Is there any better, perhaps simpler solution I haven't yet thought of?

Comment: i would use border image and gradient .. but i will get it with multiple gradient and pseudo element

Comment: Out off interest is the square of fixed pixel size or of percentage size? Also would you want to be able to resize/move the element?

Comment: Squares are of fixed size, containers can be of any size and located anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a lot of elements or a compicate way with mulitple gradient here is another idea using special character:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(lightblue, lightblue) 5px 0/calc(100% - 10px) 100% no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 180px;
  letter-spacing: 180px;
}

.box:before {
  content: "\25A1\25A1\25A1";
  letter-spacing: 85px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.box:after {
  content: "\25A1\25A1\25A1";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 85px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  □□
</div>
```

Here is anoher more generic solution using multiple background, SVG and CSS variable to make the code light:

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  --square: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><rect width="20" height="20" fill="transparent" stroke="%23000" stroke-width="3"/></svg>');
}

.overlay:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  background-image: 
    var(--square), var(--square), var(--square), 
    var(--square),                var(--square), 
    var(--square), var(--square), var(--square);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-position: 
    top    left, top center   , top    right,
    center left,                center right,
    bottom left, bottom center, bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box overlay"></div>

<div class="box overlay" style="width:100px;"></div>
<div class="box overlay" style="height:100px;"></div>

<p class="overlay"> some text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to replicate the eight squares on the border, not the blue, empty container. The container should contain anything, a paragraph for example. So the 180px line-height won't work... I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @drake035 i know :) i simply gave a solution that you need to adjust ;) .. 180px line height is an example in this case, you need to find the formula to make it generic